# How can I use google translation API in Django with python

Tags: python, django, api, google-translation-api

I am using Django to create a project where I can change the language of website where user can use the page in any language they are comfortable with.
But I am not sure how to implement google translate API in Django can anyone help me.
I know that we can install google translation API using

"$ pip install googletrans"

but how can we implement this in Django framework.
I am new to python. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello! Please, have a look for the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/python), where you can find information regarding Python client library. Additionally, check step-by-step tutorial on YT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YapTts_An9A Let me know if you find it  useful.

Answer (score 0):

there is a pip package which you can import in your templates and there will be google translate button.
[django-google-translate](https://pypi.org/project/django-google-translate/) visit this and you will find more information.

Answer (score 0):

you can use googletrans library. Here I include the library. https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/ Here the documentation also availabe.
It is easy to use.

*pip install googletran*s

```
    from googletrans import Translator

    translator = Translator()
    data = await translator.translate('යුනිකෝඩ් ', dest='ec', src='si').text()
```